# Security Reinforcement: How to collect visitors' IP addresses in Grails Framework?

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, spring

How to make a logging list of Users' IP addresses, should this be done via tomcat or grails or a combination of both

Answer (score 2):

```
ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()
```

Comment: There are indeed circumstances wherein this won't work. E.g. the server is sitting behind a proxy and would thus only retrieve the proxy's IP as remote addr instead. When you're using a bit decent proxy, the original IP is often just present in another request header, usually the `X_FORWARDED_FOR` one.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I am also using the request.getRemoteAddr() to store client IP address to database.